# Determine the average of $\mathrm{g}(x)$ by having the average values of $\mathrm{f}(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to work with the averages formula

$$\frac{1}{b-a} \ \int_a^b \mathrm{f}(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I'm not sure how to get what I'm being asked, I am treating the formulas for every interval as equations but I don't get any result

[image]

Comment: The front should be $\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Comment: I changed your $\frac{1}{a-b}$ to $\frac{1}{b-a}$ because if the integral is over $[a,b]$ then $a\le b$ and so the length of the integral is $b-a$ and not $a-b$.

Comment: Oh yes, my bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\displaystyle \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{b-a} \left( \int_a^c f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x +\int_c^b f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\right)$

---

**Hint** $\displaystyle \int_{-3}^6 g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = 18+\int_{-3}^6 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$

---

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_{-3}^{-1} f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = 5 \iff \int_{-3}^{-1} f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = 10$

Comment: I am trying that, but I don't know what to do with f(x) since I can't really integrate it

Comment: You don't have to. You already have the result of the integration - the average value.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6+3} \int_{-3}^6 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{6+3}( \int_2^6 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x +\int_{-1}^2 f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-3}^{-1} f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x)$ ? I don't understand how do I extract f(x) from the formula so I can replace it in g(x) = 2 + f(x)

Comment: Correct. I'll edit above to add hint for $g$.

Comment: Can you explain to me how do I use the given averages... I can't just replace the integrals for those values since they have their own 1/b-a... which is not 1/9 :s

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta Edited answer with info.

Comment: I used a very long process, but I got 16/3, which should be ok.